# Verifying a cosine FourierTransform

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

On page 31 of this [standard reference](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf) we have the following relation:

[image]

I wanted to use mathematica to verify this transform numerically for some example values. So I type in:

```
transf[a_, c_, \[Beta]_, w_] =
  (\[Pi] (Cos[\[Pi]/\[Beta] - 
  ( a c)/\[Beta]] Cosh[\[Pi]/\[Beta] + (c w)/\[Beta]] - 
  Cos[\[Pi]/\[Beta] + (a c)/\[Beta]] Cosh[\[Pi]/\[Beta] - 
  ( c w)/\[Beta]]))/(\[Beta] Sin[ c] (Cosh[(2 \[Pi] w)/\[Beta]] -
  Cos[(2 \[Pi] a)/\[Beta]]))
```

And try, i.e. the following

```
NIntegrate[Cosh[a x]/(Cosh[\[Beta] x]+Cos[c])Cos[x Zeta[3]]
 /.a->0 /.\[Beta]->2/.c->\[Pi]/3,{x,0,Infinity}]
```

> `0.377469`

Trying to evaluate the analytic right hand side at the same point gives however:

```
transf[0, \[Pi]/3, 2, Zeta[3]]
```

> `0`

Which is clearly not the same. What is the issue here? Is the numeric integration in Mathematica wrong? Is there a typo in the reference? Did I misunderstand some of the input? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: FWIW `FourierCosTransform` produces an analytic result for `c=Pi/2 , a=0` that agrees with your `NIntegrate` and not with the reference expression.